# How to Override Add Product button on Opportunity which should display records which satisfy some filter Criteria?

Tags: apex

When an user clicks on "Add Product" on an opportunity, they should be presented with a  list of products that have a check box checked records .

i.e. the filter for this field should already be done when we present the products list to the users.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. What have you tried so far? Have you looked into Salesforce URL hacking?